# is it possible to lock a user into a give directory tree in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to lock a user into a given directory tree. That is he/she can cd deeper into the tree but no higher out of the tree. Everything else in the environment should be the exact same.

Edit:
How can I do this without chroot. I am launching a bash via objective-c can creating a terminal-like application. I need to user to be able to access /usr/include and all the other places on they system, I just need them to be locked into a directory structure. chroot seems to require root privileges to run. Running bash in restrictive mode is to restrictive.

Comment: Soooo, you want a chroot?

Comment: Also, this should be on [unix.SE].

Comment: Not really programming related -- unless asking how this can be done programmatically, which does not seem to be the case. Voting to migrate.

Answer (score 2):

Is [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) what you are looking for?

Comment: A chroot wouldnt work well for this as the `etc`, `bin`, `lib`, etc... directories will need to exist inside the chroot. You can set up bind mounts, but it would get extremely messy.

Answer (score 1):

*What are you trying to achieve?*

If you want protection from the users, it's a [security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) issue, and I can't imagine how reducing their ability to `cd` into any directory could be of any benefit. You could try a VM (pretty secure) or chroot jail (not very secure).

If you want to protect them from themselves, you can simply override `cd` in `.bashrc` like this:

```
cd() {
    builtin cd "$@"
    if [[ ! "$(pwd)" =~ ^$HOME ]]
    then
        echo "Escape is futile"
        builtin cd - >/dev/null
    fi
}
```

Comment: "chroot jail not very secure"?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot#Limitations) [you](http://kerneltrap.org/Linux/Abusing_chroot) [go](http://www.bpfh.net/simes/computing/chroot-break.html). I especially like these quotes: "incompetent people implementing security solutions are a real problem" + "chroot is not and never has been a security tool."

Comment: No, its not perfect, no one security implementation is. But I do argue that it provides quite a bit of security for minimal effort (compared to more drastic measures such as selinux or grsecurity).

Answer (score 0):

Without help from the kernel you won't be able to fully restrict the user inside a directory. Even using strace/ktrace is limited because it will probably be complex to implement correctly and make the user experience a nightmare.

If you use FreeBSD, look at the jail sub system. It is really efficient. Else, you need to chroot your users, if they are logging via

Comment: Re: jails, on recent versions of Fedora, there's the "sandbox" program which can behave somewhat similarly to jails for this context.